# How to map with the help of Automapper (TypeScript) the entries of an array filled with different DTOs?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, nestjs, automapper

I'm using the TypeScript library ["Automapper"](https://automapperts.netlify.app/docs/nestjs) in my [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) backend to convert an answer of MongoDb/[Mongoose](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#discriminators) to an DTO. That's how the answer looks like:

```
{
    "_id": "mongo-object-id",
    "widgets": [
      {
        "id": "UUID",
        "type": "IMAGE",
        "zIndex": "0",
        "position": { "x": 1, "y": 2 },
        "pinned": false,
        "height":500,
        "width":1000
      },
      {
        "id": "UUID",
        "type": "CONVERSATION",
        "zIndex": "1",
        "position": { "x": 3, "y": 7 },
        "pinned": false,
        "participants": ["UUID1","UUID2"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

My problem is, that I don't know how to convert the entries of the "widgets" array to different DTOs (ImageDTO, ConversationDTO) based on the "type" attribute/discriminator.

How can I solve that?

Currently I use the following:

```
mapper.createMap(MeetingSpace, MeetingSpaceDto).forMember(
        (destination) => destination.widgets,
        mapWith(WidgetDto, Widget, (source) => source.widgets)
      );
```

But I have to find a way to map a "Widget" to an "ImageDto" or "ConversationDto" because of the "type".

```
mapWith(ImageDto, Widget, (source) => source.widgets)
mapWith(ConversationDto, Widget, (source) => source.widgets)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit late - but I just came across the same need.

You need to define the mapping from Widget to ImageDTO

```
createMap(mapper, Widget, ImageDTO);
```

Then use the map function on the collection:

```
return source.widgets.map(widget => mapper.map(widget, Widget, ImageDTO);
```